# Beautifulsoup how to add something to a column if element is not showing

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page so I can see what is in stock and what is not.

When something is in stock this element appears: class_='cta primary'

But when something is out of stock this element disappears and instead shows: class_='cta nostock'

Can someone show me what to add to get both in stock and out of stock?

Many thanks

```
#--Web scraping packages
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
#Pandas/numpy for data manipulation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

final_list=[]

url = 'https://www.hillsidehanddryers.com/dryers/?page={}'


#for pg in range(1, 3):
pg = url #+ '?page=' + str(pg)
r=requests.get(pg)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for paragraph in soup.find_all('div',class_='innermargin'):  # <section class='review_content'>
        try:
         title=paragraph.find('h4').text.strip()
         price=paragraph.find('p',class_='price').text.strip()
         outstock=paragraph.find('a',class_='cta nostock').text.strip()
         instock=paragraph.find('a', class_='cta primary').text.strip()
           
         final_list.append([title,price,outstock])
        except AttributeError:
            pass

df = pd.DataFrame(final_list,columns=['Title','price','outstock'])
df.head(100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if `class` of `cta nostock` exists and set value to **Out Of Stock** else set value *In Stock*:

```
stock = 'Out Of Stock' if item.find('a',class_='cta nostock') else 'In Stock'
```

#### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}

r =requests.get('https://www.hillsidehanddryers.com/dryers/?page={}')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

data = []

for item in soup.select('div.part'):
    title=item.find('h4').text.strip()
    price=item.find('p',class_='price').text.strip()
    stock = 'Out Of Stock' if item.find('a',class_='cta nostock') else 'In Stock'
    data.append({
        'title':title,
        'price':price,
        'stock':stock
    })
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head(100)
```